# How to deploy angular app that completely relies on external API to retrieve and store data?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

For an angular app that completely relies on external API to retrieve and store data, is NodeJS necessary for deployment? What are the other possible methods of deployment? Currently, I use it for local development and plan on using it in combination with Nginx for production. However, NodeJS is not doing anything except launching index.html. So should I remove NodeJS altogether and simply use Nginx alone?

Comment: Depends how you plan to serve the html and other static resources. It's not uncommon to use node locally then upload public files to a server that is already configured to deliver them

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have altered my question. Would you mind commenting on that as well?

Comment: if nginx will deliver the html and other resources already, probably woudn't need node

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to host it using any web host, they all equally host HTML only sites, and this solution is pretty inexpensive.  Hosts like Hostgator, web.com etc., will allow you to upload the site via FTP.

A second choice is to host it using a web server (Nginx), but this is probably the most costly.  You can host your own server in any cloud service (Amazon would be EC2 for instance) and then host your files there. This is probably not a good option for you. The only reason to use this type of solution is if you need the server to host code, so if you were using node to talk to a database for instance.

A 'pro' option may be to put them in S3 on AWS, and host it that way, it is pretty inexpensive.

Here is a link explaining how to host on Amazon - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html